# Selecting an Angular Bootstrap static tab from controller

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a set of static angular bootstrap tabs:

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="Static title" select="remember(0)">Static content</tab>
  <tab heading="Another title" select="remember(1)">Static content</tab>
  <tab heading="Another title" select="remember(2)">Static content</tab>
</tabset>
```

I created a function to store which tab was last selected. However, I can't seem to find a way, from the controller, to  *select* a given tab.

The example on the site is with *dynamic* tabs, created from an array in a repeater. So then something like `$scope.tabs[0].active = true;` would suffice.

However, these tabs are just markup not an array, and it does not say how (or if) it's possible to select one of these tabs from the controller.

I'd prefer to use static tabs if I can, since I'd rather not use includes.

Thoughts? I forked the example from UI-Bootstrap [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZBO0VHQ7kvLZ66hH2VWK?p=preview).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `active` attribute similar to how you would use `ng-model` on an input. e.g.

```
<tabset>
  <tab active="tabs[0].active" heading="Static title" select="remember(0)">Static content</tab>
  <tab active="tabs[1].active" heading="Another title" select="remember(1)">Static content</tab>
  <tab active="tabs[2].active" heading="Another title" select="remember(2)">Static content</tab>
</tabset>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues that I have faced using the ui-bootstrap is the way it uses the isolated scope - the conclusion in my experience is that dynamic content is not well suited when used in conjunction with ui-bootstrap tabs.

Having said that, I have forked your [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sUsE32GubalZtBbu9kPj?p=preview). The key is to used the `active` attribute of the tab and manage that via your controller.

Based on the comment, I have hooked up the `remember` function to toggle the state of the tabs. In addition, I have also set up a controller `init` method to pull the `activeTab` from sessionStorage.

See the [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/nnFIbSnnZYrkrel7qGEi).

Check the console output to verify that the `activeTabs` state is correctly maintained

Comment: So how would I set the other x tabs (here 2) to inactive easily?  I forked your plunker with my code for setting/remembering, but so far it's only setting the active tab from the array: http://plnkr.co/edit/jhH9NP49ruMJyQGw5Ef2?p=preview